# Test internal representation of the type (kind)

Tags: fortran

When testing for computer performance with different internal representation (kind), the code stays more or less the same, except the definition of the tested parameters (kind=1;kind=2). I have tried to build different modules.

```
    module var_1
    implicit none
    real(8), allocatable :: x(:,:),xi(:,:),xt(:,:)
    integer(kind=1), allocatable :: z(:,:)
    end module var_1

    module var_2
    implicit none
    real(8), allocatable :: x(:,:),xi(:,:),xt(:,:)
    integer(kind=2), allocatable :: z(:,:)
    end module var_2
```

Also there is a global module that defines the parameters that do not change:

```
    module global
    integer :: i,j,n,p,nProcessors,s,v,w,infodpotrf,infodpotri,mkl_get_max_threads
    integer, dimension(3) :: ni = [100, 1000, 10000], pi = [100, 1000, 10000]
    integer, dimension(5) :: nProcessorsi = [1, 2, 4, 6, 12]
    real(8):: u,myone= 1.d0,t11,t22
    real:: t2,t1
    include 'omp_lib.h'
    end module global
```

Than in program part we call subroutines defined later on:

```
   program test
   call matrix_multi_inv_1
   call matrix_multi_inv_2
   end program test
```

Subroutines:

```
    subroutine matrix_multi_inv_1
    use global 
    use var_1

    open (unit=100,file="results.txt",status="unknown")

    do s=1,5
      nProcessors = nProcessorsi(s)
      CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(nProcessors)
      do v=1,3
        n=ni(v)
        do w=1,3
          p=pi(w)
          allocate(x(n,n),z(n,p),xi(n,n),xt(n,n))
            do i=1,n
               do j=1,p
                  call random_number(u)
                  z(i,j)=real(floor(u*3),8)
               enddo
            enddo

       1000 format(3(a20),2(i10),2(f15.3),i10)

            t11=omp_get_wtime()
            call cpu_time(t1)
            x=matmul(z,transpose(z))
            t22=omp_get_wtime()
            call cpu_time(t2)

            write(100,1000) 'x_integer_kind_1', 'G_real_8', 'matmul', n, p, t22-t11,t2-t1, mkl_get_max_threads() 

          deallocate(x,z,xi,xt)
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
    end subroutine matrix_multi_inv_1

    subroutine matrix_multi_inv_2
    use global 
    use var_1

    open (unit=100,file="results.txt",status="unknown")

    do s=1,5
      nProcessors = nProcessorsi(s)
      CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(nProcessors)
      do v=1,3
        n=ni(v)
        do w=1,3
          p=pi(w)
          allocate(x(n,n),z(n,p),xi(n,n),xt(n,n))
            do i=1,n
               do j=1,p
                  call random_number(u)
                  z(i,j)=real(floor(u*3),8)
               enddo
            enddo

       1000 format(3(a20),2(i10),2(f15.3),i10)

            t11=omp_get_wtime()
            call cpu_time(t1)
            x=matmul(z,transpose(z))
            t22=omp_get_wtime()
            call cpu_time(t2)

            write(100,1000) 'x_integer_kind_2', 'G_real_8', 'matmul', n, p, t22-t11,t2-t1, mkl_get_max_threads() 

          deallocate(x,z,xi,xt)
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
    end subroutine matrix_multi_inv_2
```

And here comes the problem. Subroutines are exactly the same except for the call module part. I have tried to use a contain statement in the subroutine but this does not work if the inner subroutine is called. Also I have tried to use subroutine with attribute but my compiler reports an error:

> A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.

Does anyone know a nice solution how to optimize the code. When 10 different variation of different internal representation is tested than this code becomes just too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem is usually solved by poor man templates using include`. You move the common part to another file and the just do

```
subroutine matrix_multi_inv_1
    use var_1
    include "common.f90"
end subroutine

subroutine matrix_multi_inv_2
    use var_2
    include "common.f90"
end subroutine
```

C preprocessor can be used for more power.

Answer (score 0):

Why not source out the relevant code into a file `print_huge.inc.F90` to be included into modules:

```
! No module ... required
interface print_huge
  module procedure print_huge
end interface

contains

subroutine print_huge(a)
  real(kind=mykind),intent(in) :: a

  print *, huge(a)
end subroutine

! no end module
```

Then you can `include` this into different modules `print_huge_N`:

```
module print_huge_4
  integer,parameter :: mykind = 4

  include 'print_huge.inc.F90'
end module

module print_huge_8
  integer,parameter :: mykind = 8

  include 'print_huge.inc.F90'
end module

module print_huge_16
  integer,parameter :: mykind = 16

  include 'print_huge.inc.F90'
end module
```

Note, that each module has its own `mykind` defined!

For convenience you can make use of the interface defined to bundle the modules into one "super module" (inspired by the example in the book of Arjen Markus):

```
module print_huge_all
  use print_huge_4
  use print_huge_8
  use print_huge_16
end module
```

Then your main application would simply look like:

```
program huge_program
  use print_huge_all
  real(kind=4)  :: a1
  real(kind=8)  :: a2
  real(kind=16) :: a3

  call print_huge(a1)
  call print_huge(a2)
  call print_huge(a3)
end program
```

With the following output:

```
./a.out 
   3.40282347E+38
   1.7976931348623157E+308
   1.18973149535723176508575932662800702E+4932
```

The subroutine resides in the include file and does not need to be adjusted to all `kind`s. Of course, you could directly access all modules directly and/or "rename" the subroutines using the `=>` operator.